# Undefined function or variable in MATLAB,how to setup parameters?

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB code,beggining of the code

```
function [hm,sm] = SKSClab(filename,data_type,maxk,true_labels,plot_flag)
addpath('util')

%Main check
if(nargin<2)

fprintf('\nPossible data types:\n')
fprintf('\nnet_unw -> unweighted network\n')
fprintf('\nnet_w -> weighted network\n')
fprintf('\nvector -> (generic) data points\n')
fprintf('\nts -> time series\n')
fprintf('\nimg -> image\n')
error('You should provide at least a data type as second argument to the SKSClab function!')
```

end
%Loading data

```
fprintf('\nLoading data...\n');

if(strcmp(data_type,'net_unw'))

network = load([filename,'.txt'],'-ascii');
```

I have tried to to run code like this

```
SKSClab(proba.txt,3,6,1)
Undefined variable "proba" or function "proba.txt".
```

But

```
Undefined variable "proba" or function "proba.txt".
```

What should I change?

Comment: I'm pretty sure strings need to be placed in quotes, try SKSClab('proba.txt', 3, 6, 1)

Comment: @rossb83 Thanks,that was the issue!

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function with
 `SKSCLab('proba.txt',3,6,1)`
otherwise matlab does not know that proba.txt is a string and not a variable